# Aws Glue catalog table retention

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena

From aws documentation this one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-tables.html, they mentioned this
"
Retention – Number (integer), not more than None.
The retention time for this table.
"
Anyone knows what does it do?

Answer (score 2):

Glue does not do anything with the table retention property. that parameter comes directly from Hive. Therefore, if the use case here is using Hive on EMR only then this parameter becomes meaningful.